# Problem with parameters from fitting

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I am trying to fit the following data (called `TflogqIND`):

```
TflogqIND={{0., 36.4886}, {Log[2]/Log[10], 37.1485}, {Log[5]/Log[10], 
  38.3859}, {1, 39.2263}, {Log[20]/Log[10], 39.8772}, {Log[30]/
  Log[10], 40.0107}}
```

to the following equation:

```
 eqn = ((log10q - Log10[qref]) == 
       c1*(Tfp - Tfpref)/(c2 + (Tfp - Tfpref))); (*WLF equation*)
    model = Tfp /. Solve[eqn, Tfp][[1]] // FullSimplify;
    constIND = {Tfpref -> 39.2263, 
       qref -> 10};
    modelIND = model /. (constIND // Rationalize) // FullSimplify;
    
    nlmIND = NonlinearModelFit[
       TflogqIND, {modelIND, c1 > 5, c2 > 5}, {c1, c2}, log10q];
```

As you can see from plotting:

`Show[ ListPlot[TflogqIND, PlotMarkers -> Style[\[FilledSquare], 18, Red],  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameStyle -> 16,  LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 10}, ImageSize -> Large,  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8],  PlotRange -> All],  Plot[nlmIND[log10q], {log10q, 0, 1.4}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]]`

The model seems to describe the data well. However, the parameters (obtained from `nlmIND["BestFitParameters"]` with {c1 -> 1331.87, c2 -> 3520.53}) don't make any sense. Usually c1 and c2 parameters are from 1 to around 100 or 200 at the most.

I think there must be a mistake somewhere but I cannot see it. How can I fix the model to give better c1 and c2 values and better describe the data using that equation?

Comment: "Usually `c1` and `c2` parameters are from 1 to around 100 or 200 at the most." - then you should have put a constraint like that in your fit, no? `{modelIND, 200 > c1 > 5, 200 > c2 > 5}` Also, you would still want a way to figure out good initial values for these parameters.

Comment: For this particular dataset and model there is no finite set of parameter estimates that maximizes the likelihood or minimizes the mean square error.  The estimate for `c1` can be found in terms of `c2` but then the mean square error keeps getting smaller for increasing values of `c2`.  I'll write up the details tomorrow as it's too late at night for me to do so now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that with the available data and proposed model there are no finite values of the two parameters ($c_1$ and $c_2$) that can minimize the sum of squares (which is essentially what `NonlinearModelFit` uses in this case).  In this case lack of numerical precision is not the culprit (although it is one of the usual suspects in many cases).

The "good" news is that an infinite number of solutions will give almost the same set of predictions.  The "bad" news is that one can't place any interpretation on any particular chosen set of parameters.

Here's why.  To avoid confusion with the lack of numerical precision culprit `Rationalize` the data:

```
TflogqIND = {{0., 36.4886}, {Log[2]/Log[10], 37.1485}, {Log[5]/Log[10], 38.3859},
  {1, 39.2263}, {Log[20]/Log[10], 39.8772}, {Log[30]/Log[10], 40.0107}};
TflogqIND = Rationalize[TflogqIND, 0];
```

The resulting model ends up being the following:

```
modelIND = 392263/10000 + (c2 (-1 + log10q))/(1 + c1 - log10q);
```

The sum of squares to be minimized is the following:

```
sumOfSquares = Total[(#[[2]] - modelIND /. log10q -> #[[1]])^2 & /@ TflogqIND];
```

The value of `c2` that minimizes the sum of squares (assuming that there is a value that does so) is found by finding where the derivative of the sumOfSquares with respect to `c2`:

```
solc2 = Solve[D[sumOfSquares, c2] == 0, c2][[1]];
```

So we now have a solution for the minimum of the sum of squares given a value of `c1`.  Plotting that minimum function against values of `c1` shows that the absolute minimum is never realized for any finite value of `c1`:

```
Plot[sumOfSquares /. solc2, {c1, 0, 50000}]
```

[image: Plot of sum of squares over values of c1]

The limit of the sum of squares as `c1 -> ∞` is

```
Limit[sumOfSquares /. solc2, c1 -> ∞] // N
(* 0.312188 *)
```

So any set of values with `c2/.solc2` that has a sum of squares close to 0.312188 will give an almost identical fit.

Consider `c1 = 4000`.  Then the values of `c2` and the sum of squares are

```
solc2 /. c1 -> 4000 // N
(* {c2 -> 10569.9} *)

sumOfSquares /. solc2 /. c1 -> 4000 // N
(* 0.31263 *)
```

With `c1 = 40000` we have

```
solc2 /. c1 -> 40000 // N
(* {c2 -> 105685.} *)

sumOfSquares /. solc2 /. c1 -> 40000 // N
(* 0.312232 *)
```

Finally:  given the data that you have, just fitting `a + b*log10q` might be a better approach.

Comment: Thank you so much JimB for the nice explanation !

Comment: JimB one question: with the approach you show with the sum of squares close to 0.312, it is not very clear to me what would be the resulting values of C1 and C2. Could you clarify that if you don't mind. Thanks !

Comment: @John  Added explicit examples for obtaining `c2` given `c1`.